# Macbook WiFi card not working

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook 1.83ghz.

I installed Snow Leopard and the WiFi crashed (?)

It was barely functioning before, but now all it can do is detect names of routers.

I haven't done anything as I don't know what to do.

How do i run a diagnostic before I have to buy a new WiFi card?

Comment: We need to work with you to clarify the question. You wifi card is working as far as detecting the networks.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do some information collecting then do some testing.

> Click on the Apple (top left)
>
> About this Mac
>
> More Info
>
> System Report
>
> Now look for Network and WiFi

There you will see the information about your WiFi card and the status of the connections.

It looks like this:
[image]

As next step I suggest to do some Diagnostics.

Than open the Network Diagnostics to test your WiFi connection.

> Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, and then click Network.
>
> Click “Assist me,” click Diagnostics, and then follow the onscreen
>   instructions.

This test will tell you about your WiFi card and connections.